# Ocelot doesn't rederict to microservice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microservices, ocelot

I'm trying to implement my microservice application.
I've Catalog API microservice on localhost:5001 - base CRUD.
I want to implement Api Gateway using Ocelot.

Catalo.API launSettings.json:

```
"reservation_system.Catalo.Api": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger/index.html",
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

Program.cs from API Gateway:

```
  public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((host, config) =>
                {
                    config
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{host.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    config.AddJsonFile("configuration.json");
                })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddOcelot();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
            app.UseMvc();
            await app.UseOcelot();
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to reach my catalog API through http://localhost:50121/catalog
I'm getting "Hello World!" answer.
What's an issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ocelot middleware is not executed because you are short-circuiting the request pipeline by calling the `Run()` delegate and writing to the response stream.

The order that middleware components are registered in the `Configure` method matters.  These components are invoked in the same order they are added.

So if you move `await app.UseOcelot();` up, into the `Configure()` method, right before the `app.Run()`, the Ocelot middleware will be executed.